# Método em C# para verificar uma string

Tags: c#

Galera, alguém aí poderia me dar uma força, ajudando a criar esse método em C#?

Método  para verificar parênteses em uma string de 
entrada. Por exemplo, o método deve retornar `verdadeiro` para os seguintes valores:

> ((5+2)*2) + (40+20) + (((76-1)-3)*1)
>
> O Fulano (aquele que estava na padaria hoje ) procurou por você.

E retornar `Falso` para as seguintes valores:

> %:)
>
> @:)

Comment: Por “ASP.NET” você quer dizer “C#”, certo?

Comment: Sim amigo pode me ajudar?

Comment: Precisa ser recursivo mesmo?

Comment: sim teria que ser recursivo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução ordinária seria:

```
String texto = "(()";

int parenteses = 0;
foreach (char c in texto)
{
    if (c.Equals('(')) {
        parenteses++;
    } else if (c.Equals(')')) {
        parenteses--;
    }

    if (parenteses < 0) {
        break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(parenteses == 0);
```

#### Testes

> (() - FALSE
>
> )( - FALSE
>
> ((1+1)*2) + (10+2) + (((2-1)-1)*1) - TRUE
>
> &:) - FALSE

Basicamente ele verifica se começou parênteses e faz controle se fechou antes, caso fechou ele já interrompe o laço. Só vai estar correto se fechou todos parênteses `parenteses == 0`

### [Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/bgpHuh)

Comment: `")("` é um contra-exemplo.

Comment: @ctgPi Adaptei :)

Comment: Outros bons casos de teste: `""`, `"("`, `")"`, `"()"`, `"()()"`, `"(())"`.

Comment: @ctgPi Eu coloquei o link do `ideone` se quiser testar, em todos funcionaram, mas como o autor da pergunta mencionou parece q ele quer recursiva e me parece ser dever de casa

Comment: Eu sei que funcionam. :) Eu estou postando os casos de teste pro autor da pergunta mesmo. Não me parece óbvio que exista uma solução recursiva que não seja só um jeito tosco de fazer o `while` da sua solução.